# Xcode won't run app due to some runtime error

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcode7

Xcode keeps giving me this weird error when I run my app on a simulator.

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)
```

When I run this on my iPhone I get some

```
Coregraphics can't load
```

I deleted this folder (a friend told me too.)

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

I did find some frameworks in the trash and I pressed the "Put-back" option.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this? I'm running Xcode 7 - Beta 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this and it worked fine.

```
Step 1) Go into Xcode Preferences -> Accounts -> More Info. Hit the refresh icon.

Step 2) Clean your project. Project -> Clean.

Step 3) Force quit Xcode.

Step 4) Reboot Mac and Device.
```